# Sensors Start N Stop Working

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-touchwiz, sensors

I own a Galaxy S4 I9505 device.

Earlier I was running the stock based Custom ROM (Imperium 16.1, Android 4.4.2) on my S4 and there was no problem at all. That ROM gave me supreme performance, stability and battery life.

And then official Lollipop (5.0.1) was released by Samsung. I flashed the latest stock based custom Lollipop ROM on my device and the problem started.

Now what happens is ... **after I flash a ROM everything is working fine. But then after some uncertain period all the sensors stop working on the device.

Sometimes the issue is resolved by a simple restart, at times I have to clear the Cache and sometimes I have to clear the Cache and Dalvik Cache**.

All the sensors start working and suddenly after some time, all the sensors stop working.

I have tried all stock based Custom Lollipop ROMs and even AOSP based Lollipop ROMs, but this problem is persistent with all the Lollipop ROMS.

I am not able to decipher if this is a Software or Hardware issue.

Can anyone help me on this? Has anyone faced this type of problem?

Thanks[image]

Comment: You mentioned that the majority of the custom ROMs which your tried were all lollipop. On the other hand, Imperium 16.1 over 4.4.2 worked fine. If only you try one more custom ROM based on Kitkat or lower, you can tell whether this is a software issue or HW.  That would not solve the major issue but should lessen the worry thinking that its HW issue.

Comment: Thanks for the idea buddy ... but since I posted this question I have even tried the Stock Lollipop ROM (non-rooted) and still the same problem. Before that I flashed Imperium 16.1 (4.4.2) with clean wipe and still the problem persisted.... and now I think I will have to conclude that this is a Hardware problem .... But I still strongly believe that it could be a Software issue as well....